# Natural deduction : $\lnot \forall x.P(x) \to \exists x. \lnot P(x)$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I have to prove in the first predicate logic, using natural deduction, that $\lnot \forall x.P(x) \to \exists x. \lnot P(x)$. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) $¬∀xP(x)$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \exists x \lnot P(x)$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot P(x)$ --- assumed [b]

4) $\exists x \lnot P(x)$ --- from 3) by $\exists$-intro

5) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 4)

6) $P(x)$ --- from 3) by *Double Negation*, discharging [b]

7) $\forall x P(x)$ --- from 6) by $\forall$-intro

8) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 7)

> 9) $\exists x \lnot P(x)$ --- from 2) by *DN*, discharging [a].

Comment: I don't understand what 3 and 6 are supposed to mean, with $x$ being unquantified. Or is that the $\forall$ intro in 7? (I'm not familiar with natural deduction in particular.)

Comment: @Ian - see [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/) for an explanation of the rules.

Comment: @Ian - 3) and 6) are formula with *free* variables. They are not "specific" of *ND*; every first-order language has formulae with free vars.